# does putting your laptop to sleep instead of turning it off completely damage it?

Tags: laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I put my MacBook Pro to sleep, or shut it down every day?](https://superuser.com/questions/31141/should-i-put-my-macbook-pro-to-sleep-or-shut-it-down-every-day)

I have an  HP laptop and recently it has not been able to Start right away  and I have to restart it to get it to work!

So my question is: **does putting it to Sleep instead of turning it completely off damage the laptop?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I put my MacBook Pro to sleep, or shut it down every day?](http://superuser.com/questions/31141/should-i-put-my-macbook-pro-to-sleep-or-shut-it-down-every-day) anr/or [Is it bad to put your computer in sleep mode every time?](http://superuser.com/questions/28582/is-it-bad-to-put-your-computer-in-sleep-mode-every-time?lq=1)

Comment: @techie007 , OK ,sorry, you're right. I remove my comment.

Answer (score 0):

In a word, "No". It's designed to do this, so there is no more damage other than normal wear and tear.