# For how much time can i keep my laptop on hybernation?

Tags: laptop, power

Can i keep my laptop on hybernation for all the time.
And after using it again can i keep it in hybernation,and forever on hybernation.

Comment: If you give more specific information about your laptop (brand, model and OS) you may get a more specific answer.

Comment: Dell inspiron 3558,os-win10.

Comment: Related: [Is it bad to put your computer in sleep mode every time?](http://superuser.com/questions/28582/is-it-bad-to-put-your-computer-in-sleep-mode-every-time)

Comment: Do you mean to ask whether the battery is drained at all in Hibernation mode?

Answer (score 4):

Hibernation can be used forever, it's different to sleep.

- Sleep, most of the computer is shutdown - but power is supplied to the RAM so it doesn't lose it data.
- Hibernation, all of the computer is shutdown - the RAM is copied to the harddisk (hiberfil.sys) on windows. When the machine is turned back on, the data is copied from hardisk back to RAM so your computer is running in the same place it was running before it entered Hibernation.

You should notice that the hiberfil.sys is the same size as the RAM you have installed in the machine.

Comment: Not always the same size, but OP should note that it's really recommended to completely shut down the PC from time to time for stability reasons.

Comment: How can i check hyberfil.sys ?

Comment: Its a hidden operating system file, but it should be at the root of C:\. You may need to enable viewing hidden files and viewing system files in folder setting menu.